# Should I use test cases if my project requirement keeps changing?

Tags: testing, tdd, testcase

Requirements in my project keeps changing too frequently.  It has become very inconvenient to maintain test cases. Is it still advisable to use test cases? Or is there any good way to handle this problem?

Comment: There's no way to code around bad project management! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the pain of having unit tests.  You should stick with it.

1. You will be in a much better place when requirements settle down.
2. Without tests, you will *more* vulnerable -- when rapid change occurs, things are very likely to be broken accidentally.
3. If you abandon testing now is you are likely to not pick it back up again....

Answer (score 3):

If you have to change the code, then I think it is more important than ever to maintain the test harness. The test harness is a form of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

One more argument I will be saying to whoever tries to convince me 100% test coverage is the holy grail.

Project requirements do not change, like, altogether (unless this is very small project). There are always some assumptions, assertions, limits dictated by law of physics after all :)

I propose to go through requirements and to split them between tiers. Requirements of tier 1 are less likely to change than those of tier 2. This way you could focus on less volatile parts. Eventually requirements producer will get tired (replaced, bored).

Developers must be in poorer shape. Rapid requirement changes will get spaghetti code. Test harness can be spaghetti to some extent, but it is really a life saver to them. It is very important to keep it fit with such project organization.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged this question "TDD", think about how to implement a changed requirement via test-driven development.  In the case of a new requirement, you would write a failing test that demonstrates the absence of the new feature.  In the case of a changed requirement, you probably already have tests that show (by *passing*) that the feature is in its original state.  So, *test-drive* your development.  Change your passing tests so that they now require the new behavior - and fail - and now make them pass by implementing the changed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the opportunities to review your designs to see if there are parts that often change with changing requirements.  You can even make changes to the current design to move parts into two partitions: One that mostly stays the same and one that mostly changes.

You might be able to isolate the changing parts so that when requirements change you only need to add new code/classes.